# how to capture and hide iframe js error?

Tags: javascript

I want to hide and capture iframe js error,  the iframe is in same domain so there is no such cross site scripting issue,
any help, suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the error. Try FireBug it's a good tool to debug JS.

Answer (score 2):

Suggest you implement a JavaScript try/catch block that emits the error to some hidden form control in the IFrame:

```
try{
    //your javascript that can throw an error
}
catch(e)
{
    document.getElementById("YourHiddenControlId").value = e.Message;
}
```

You can then access the form variable within the IFRame.